# Not Equal to symbol in Hive not giving results

Tags: hive, business-objects

I am trying to write a very simple query in Hive( new to it too)  but I don't see the results

```
Select * from Table where Role !='Primary'
```

It brings results that are both primary and secondary

I also used <> and NOT IN but i don't see the results , I get the whole result set. I checked the official documentation and according to me <> or != should work

Comment: Can you add the result of `describe formatted Table;` to your post?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to see whether you have additional spaces in your Role field..

```
select * from yourtable where lower(trim(Role)) != lower('Primary');
```